# Clicking link autoscrolls to same position on next view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've got an  tag on a template running inside of an AngularJS application. It's down at the bottom of the page, so I have to scroll down to click on it. When I do click on it, the view switches out and now I'm looking at the linked view as I'd expect.

However, I'm scrolled down to the same position as I was on from the original page.  I have tried switching between ng-href and href within the  tag, but neither has an effect on the scrolling.

I like that the views are cached, so I'd rather not reload and have to make a request to the server to reload the application to this new page.

Is there an easy way to switch to this next view via the link and have it automatically show from the top of the document instead of maintaining the scroll position from the previous view? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `ngRoute` or `ui.router`?

Comment: I'm using ngRoute, but I'm not particularly bound to it or another at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a read through http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView, I realized that I needed to enable scrolling by replacing `<ng-view/>` with `<ng-view autoscroll/>`. Now it works as I'd expect.